# During container build service can't be found via dns name resolution

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-network

So, I have 3 services: DB, backend, and frontend.

I made a docker-compose file to execute everything:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:14.6-alpine
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .env.db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgres/data/pgdata
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    networks:
      - website

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./backend
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env.backend
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    volumes:
      - ./backend/config:/opt/app/config
      - ./backend/src:/opt/app/src
      - ./backend/package.json:/opt/package.json
      - ./backend/yarn.lock:/opt/yarn.lock
      - ./backend/public/uploads:/opt/app/public/uploads
    networks:
      - website
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - website
    depends_on:
      - backend

volumes:
  postgres-data:
    external: true

networks:
  website:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is my frontend/Dockerfile:

```
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY yarn.lock* package*.json ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL http://backend:1337/graphql

RUN yarn build

FROM node:16-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Also I developed a custom shell script to make sure that backend is up and running before building the frontend.
General idea there is:

```
docker compose up -d postgres backend
**wait logic**
docker compose up -d frontend
```

So, my question is why I'm getting error below during the build step ?
Services supposed to be in the same network and their name resolution should work as expected...

`Error: request to http://backend:1337/graphql failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND backend`

I tried to login into a dummy alpine image and ping backend from it, worked as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Image builds aren't connected to the Compose environment and can't connect to other containers.  Why do you need to make this connection during the image build?   What would happen if you exported the same image to a different system where you didn't need to rebuild the image from the Dockerfile?

Comment: @DavidMaze, I need to perform a build in order to publish static files. During the build I need to access my backend and fetch data...